# Are there code restrictions when adding an access panel in the ceiling below a bathroom?

Tags: plumbing, remodeling

So on the first floor there is a full bathroom without an access panel.  I would like set up the panel, but would hate the look of the access panel on the first floor which is built into the living room.  Can I set up the access panel underneath the bathroom in the basement(ceiling)?   Does that violate any code and if so any ideas on how to minimize the appearance of access panel on a first floor wall?

Comment: You say, “...set up access panel in basement ceiling.” And you say, “...minimize appearance of access panel on a first floor wall.”   Ceiling/wall??? I don’t understand.

Comment: @LeeSam - Read the double question. In the second they ask if the basement ceiling is not doable then how could the access panel on the living room wall be made to look decent.

Comment: Thanks michael I was having trouble reading that also.+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the access you want in the basement without worries unless your basement is a garage (like a daylight basement). If it is a garage then it would need to meet fire code, but if just an environmental space you could create your access similar to a standard scuttle hole for attic access, but hold it in with a few screws. As far as creating access in the wall of the living room, I have seen some very artistic covers for electrical panels in walls (that do not need tools to open) but could do the same for plumbing access. Think of a picture frame on a hinge that could be opened as a possibility.

Comment: So does that mean there are no code restriction on the access panel location other than the garage?  Sorry about the confusing double question.

Comment: You can put access panels in just about any place similar to a scuttle hole there are no limitations as long as it is sealed when not in use for living spaces, if a unfinished basement the whole area can be open so I don't see a problem unless local code has specific requirements,